# Can't install pip (python 3.7.4). It didn't installed with python. get-pip.py didn't work either

Tags: python, installation, pip

I dont understand why pip is not installed with python (I had a check mark in installer).

`py -m pip` returns `no module named pip`

I have windows 7, python 3.7.4 installed to `c:\python`.

tried different versions of python however, when i try install pip with `get-pip.py` i get:

```
C:\Python>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22308, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Temp\tmpx8wd2cnb\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <mod
ule>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible

many same errors (cant posted all of it here)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Temp\tmpx8wd2cnb\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in
 <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Will be grateful for answer.

Comment: Try `py -m ensurepip`

Comment: did you add python to the PATH?

Comment: @IainShelvington same error appears

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove yes I did

Comment: Check for `C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe`. If it's there, add the dir `C:\Python\Scripts` to `PATH`.

Comment: Maybe through the Group Policy in windows, you're not allowed to execute something, or the PATH you have, finds a different .exe. Maybe if you switch the order of Python in PATH and try to put it in front. Also, if you're admin on the box, try

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/cant-access-files-and-folders-on-windows-10/06032706-2c70-49b1-b118-6168d06f4d5d

Comment: @hoefling there is no this file

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove i puted python path in the first position, nothing changed. Watched link you gave. Set all posible permissions to all users, same error. Run cmd as admin - not helped

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing this issue because when you are installing python in the scripts folder pip is not getting installed ,I was facing the same problem 2 weeks back , when I searched the official site of python I finally found my answer to this problem.

1)Firstly install python the way you were doing that.

2)Next step is to run this command in your terminal: python -m ensurepip --default-pip

3)After running this command pip will successfully get installed to your system , check your scripts folder you will find the pip file there.

Comment: The list formatting seems to have put it all on one line.